# SOLVED! How to add onClick listener and method call with variable to prefab button dynamically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, dynamic

I have a prefab element, which has a button in it and several text and image elements. I can populate text and image elements like this:

```cs
foreach (Transform item in prefabName.transform) {
    if (item.name == "TextName") {
        item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "anything";
    }
}
```

but when trying to add onclick lister similar way, it does not work. There is no errors.

```cs
foreach (Transform item in prefabName.transform) {
    if (item.name == "ButtonName") {
        item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>()
            .text = "title";
        item.GetComponentInChildren<Button>()
            .onClick.AddListener(() => myMethod("info"));
    }
}
```

Example above renames button text to "title", dynamically, so it does find the button. But it does not attach method to onclick listener. I also tried version below with similar success.

```cs
foreach (Transform item in prefabName.transform) {
    if (item.name == "ButtonName") {
      item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "title";
      Button putikka = item.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
      putikka.onClick.AddListener(() => myMethod("info"));
    
    }
}
```

How should it be done so it would work?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This does change the text in TextName:

```
    foreach (Transform item in prefabName.transform) {
        if (item.name == "TextName") {
            item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "anything";
       }
    }
```

And this does change the title. of button "ButtonName", text that is child for the button

```
if (item.name == "ButtonName") {
        item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>()
            .text = "title";
    }
}
```

So in prefab i have

[image: TextName and ButtonName are on same level and text id child to ButtonName]

So should this ad the onclick listener and info -method call into button or it misses the button cause it targets to text that is child? How do i get it to target to button, not to text??

```
if (item.name == "ButtonName") {
       item.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { info(mesage); });
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

So now it is like:

```
Button putikka = item.GetComponent<Button>();
putikka.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "anything";
putikka.GetComponent<Button>().image.color = Color.red;
putikka.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
putikka.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate () { myMethod("info"); });
```

And what i get, is red button with text "anything" and it clicks when clicked but it has nothing in onclick... What am i doing wrong still?

Comment: If you want to get the Object that is on ButtonName you need to use `GetComponent<>`and not `GetComponentInChildren<>`

Comment: But that does not work. If i target to TextName, i need to do this (and this works):  item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "title"; Why ButtonName would be "only" GetComponent<>? (I tried that again, still no go.)

Comment: Isn't your Button Component in the ButtonName GameObject? If it is you need to get it with GetComponent<>

Comment: No it is not cause it is in prefab and added dynamically. As is TextName also.

Comment: Yeah I know I meant when you instantiated the prefab is the Button Component on the Button Name GameObject or the Text GameObject?

Comment: I make the prefab as gameobject, then loop it through to fill data and then add it to container which is actually scroll-snap asset which adds it to container. I use foreach / transform and for the ButtonName it is if (item.name == "ButtonName"){ do here change name to button and try to add onclick}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222225/discussion-between-mathewhd-and-jarno).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your Button Component is actually in a Child Object of the prefabItem. So that `item.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();` actually finds your Button Component.

[Button Component Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/script-Button.html)

If the object you want to change is on the object itself and not one of it's children use `GetComponent<>();` instead of `GetComponentInChildren<>();`

If that now works correctly you also need to ensure that you assign the EventListener in the correct way.

**Example:**

```cs
string message = "This is a dynamic message";
// Assign info method as the OnClick EventListener and give parameter message
btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { info(mesage); });
```

Comment: This works:  item.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "title"; <-- It adds name text to button. So it finds the button. At least button text? Should it be only GetComponent cause text is child to the button??

Tried like this as you seggested but no go.. 

 item.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { myMethod("info"); });

I have a mymethod adds console.log text and if i manually add it to prefabs button it works. But i need to pass variable data there so it is neccessary to get working dynamically.

Comment: @Jarno You can pass variable data in the way if done it as well. See the edit I've made. What I meant is that you need to make sure that your Prefab has a Button Component in one of it's childs or GetComponentinChildren won't work.

Comment: Yes, prefab has button component as child. This button has text as child and i can change that text components text. So i am missing something to not be able to assign onclick. 


Could it be it actually does not find the button but finds only the text which is child to button? But why it finds all my text and image fields that are on the same level in prefab as button? Buttons text is under button and works.

Comment: I have updated my main question so it might be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I was sure that i am idiot when problem occured, just could not pin point the place where the Idiocity occured. But, banged my head couple of days and figured it out.

I was adding everything directly to prefab and then made a copy of it to Content when instantiating with details in place. So that style kind of works too execept Addlisteners. So i started to give unique name to prefabs when instantiating them and also for the button. Then it was just the matter of finding button again and giving it AddListener. And it works. I learned my lesson, about making code and about idiocity. :)